# Unity animationに関する設定

Tags: unity3d, game-development

Unityでanimationを作成したのですが、座標の起点（？）のようなものが思うように扱えません
どうすればよいでしょうか？上の画像が理想で（座標のようなものが足の下にある）下の写真が
現状です（座標のようなものが腹のあたりにある）。どうすれば下の画像を上の画像のように設定できるでしょうか？
[image: 画像の説明をここに入力][image: 画像の説明をここに入力]